# dynamically populate grids inside a grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF. here I'm having following static grid

**Main Grid**
[image]

frame for child grid like this

**Child Grid**

[image]

I have a main grid, I'm trying to dynamically generate child grids and populate it inside Main Grid Column 0

Final outcome I'm trying to get like below

[image]

here I'm trying populate a collection of items with some styles (with separate block for each collection item property).

so for each collection item I want to generate a grid and bind that collection property names and values inside of a grid here in above picture red color represent grid for a collection item, black color grid is main grid.

really appreciate suggest an idea or propose better solution for this purpose

**Edit:**

upto now I tried following, here as child grid I'm trying to populate `icTodoList` grid 3 times, but here its only populate 1 time

*XML file*

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="147*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="220*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid Name="icTodoList" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10,10,2941" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="268">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="79*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="99*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="63*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="29*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Completion}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Completion}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Completion}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

*Code Behind file*

```
    public WindowPanelConstructor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<TodoItem> items = new List<TodoItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new TodoItem() { Title = "Title" + i.ToString(), Completion = "Completion" + i.ToString(), Description = "Description" + i.ToString() });
            icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
        }      


    }

    public class TodoItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Completion { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Use an ItemsControl.

Comment: can I put a grid inside this ItemsControl ?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to, but you have my permission.

Comment: @EdPlunkett actually my actual requirement is like this, I have a main grid ,  I want to populate a collection of items with some styles (with separate block for each collection item property). so for each collection item I want to generate a grid and bind that collection property name and value inside of a grid [here in this picture](http://i.imgur.com/mp9A4Py.jpg)  red color represent grid  for a collection item, black color grid is main grid. if you suggesting alternative, better solution for this purpose I like to proceed with it

Comment: Use an ItemsControl. If you have already have a DataTemplate for the items (if that's what "I have template for child grid" is intended to convey), that should be a snap. It won't be too hard in any case. ItemsControl is lavishly documented.

Comment: @EdPlunkett extremely sorry for my mistake, by meaning "template" , I just want to give the idea that I'm trying to create a frame for each collection item , can I do this without gird , just want to populate each colection item property value with separate block and loop them

Comment: Do you already have a collection of items that you want to display in the red grid? 1) Show me the code for those items in your question. 2) Show me the code for the collection in your question. That is code for **TWO THINGS**. Two things. Show both. Put both code in your question. Thank you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett As you said I tried this  [this is XML file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/xn4Kd) and [this is code](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/RLBnx)

Comment: Kez, I think you have valid question, if you want to add controls dynamically then I would use user controls that is already have a set grids then stack them in the main grid rather than adding grids each time.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think it is a valid technical question and  I don't think it is too broad. Just because no one has ever tried this technique before that doesn't make it broad. What the author wanted to do with his technique is his/her requirement. I think this question should not be put on hold.

Comment: @Jegan "Here's a wireframe, please implement the UI for me" is a quite broad question. "ItemsControl, DataTemplate, blah blah" isn't really an answer, and I don't think a lot of folks around here would think it is one. All that does is point him in the right direction. You're right, this is a debatable case. But this is a questioner who has trouble with simple requests like "put the code in the question".

Comment: @kez Put the code in the question like I asked you to, thanks.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Author is a beginner to WPF of cause he wouldn't have a clue how to code this in the first place, that is why he is asking for help. By blocking the question, no one can answer the technical capabilities behind this question.

Comment: @Jegan I'm still here trying to help him.

Comment: Ok, I have an example code, how to dynamically add grids in WPF, if required.

Comment: @EdPlunkett my question updated

Comment: @kez Thanks for the code. BTW don't put a * next to all the widths. Find out what the * means before you use it. More to come.

Comment: @Jegan "add controls dynamically then I would use user controls that is already have a set grids then stack them in the main grid rather than adding grids each time." can you show me example of this or can you explain more if you okay

Comment: @kez At first glance, what you've got looks good to me, for the most part. Why are you binding Title, Completion, and Description so many times in the template?

Comment: @EdPlunkett just for demo purpose I bind Title, Completion, Description 3 times in one grid, :) , actually it have has 9 properties :)

Comment: @kez Fair enough. Is it working for you now?

Comment: Nope :( this is how it looks like now,http://i.imgur.com/nqcY5aP.png  I'm trying to loop this child grid but its not

Comment: @Jegan if you an example code,"how to dynamically add grids in WPF" can you please share here

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example (I set the background of each grid to be different colour, this is just an example) to get you started, you can expand this by adding your own methods.

**In Code:**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // get the reference of the column definition of the main grid, then set your new column definition as required.
        var coldef = MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions;
        coldef.Add(new ColumnDefinition(){Name = "col1", Width=new GridLength(100.0)});
        coldef.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Name = "col2", Width = new GridLength(100.0) });
        coldef.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Name = "col2", Width = new GridLength(100.0) });

        // now add the child grids dynamically as many as you like.
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            var  colour1 = (byte)(50 * i);
            var colour2 = (byte)(100 * i);
            var grid1 = new Grid()
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(100, colour1, colour2)),
            };
            grid1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);

            // get the reference to the row definition the child grid, then set the rows as required.
            var rowDef = grid1.RowDefinitions;
            rowDef.Add(new RowDefinition() { Name = "Row1", Height = new GridLength(100.0) });
            rowDef.Add(new RowDefinition() { Name = "Row2", Height = new GridLength(100.0) });

            // add nesting child grids as many as you like.
            for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                var r = (byte)(50 * i);
                var g = (byte) (100 * i);
                var grid2 = new Grid()
                {
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, 255)),

                };
                grid2.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);

                // add grid 3 to grid 2
                grid1.Children.Add(grid2);
            }

            // Add grid1 to main grid.
            MainGrid.Children.Add(grid1);

        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleProgressBar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can see in my xaml code, there is only one grid, that is the main grid that is used in the C# code above.

Comment: thnks ill apply this and let u know here